# How could I earn the effect that I want?

Tags: html, css

I want to get my school's page navbar effect that is about if a navbar item is on hover then that makes a white border on the item's bottom. 
(https://www.kecskemet.piarista.hu/%C3%B3voda/h%C3%ADrek for example just move the cursor on a navbar item)

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}

.thumbnail {
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.thumbnail:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

.jumbotron {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.tested {
  font-size: 140%;
}

.bug {
  padding: 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.navbar-inverse {
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.navbar-inverse:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.weboldalroltext {
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

body {
  padding-top: 70px;
}

.mainHeader {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.navbar {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Sanyigarázs</a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav navbar-nav stroke">
          <li><a href="rolunk.html">Rólunk</a></li>
          <li><a href="kapcsolat.html">Kapcsolat</a></li>
          <li><a href="weboldalrol.html">Weboldalról</a></li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

I tried a lot of things but nothing helped me maybe I am still bad at CSS but I need your help guys thanks if you will answer me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect all the style on the 'a' tag of the site you've linked you can notice they also have this kind of style code on the 'a' tag:

```
a:after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: solid 3px #fff;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: transform 250ms ease-in-out;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
a:hover:after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

So you can simply add this code to your css and you would achieve the result you desire. Here is an example of the effect applied on your code [JSfiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/RaySoy/mh4voew5/)

**Some explanation of what they did**:

With the using of the pseudo-class and pseudo-element on the html tag 'a' they have added a bottom border to **all** the html tags 'a'.

 Also with 'scaleX' equal to 0(Default value 1) they have initialized the tag 'a' to width 0.

 As you can see the css property 'scaleX' become equal to 1 when you go with your cursor over the html tag 'a' because you trigger the css pseudo-class ':hover' added on the html tag 'a'.

 There is a kind of fluent movement between the scaleX from 0 to 1 and vice versa because of the css property 'tansition' that act on the value changes of the 'transform' property.

**Documentation**:

- [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) you can find some explanation about pseudo-classes.
- [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) you can find some explanation of pseudo-elements.
- [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scaleX) you can find some explanation of scaleX.
- [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) you can find some explanation of transition.

Let me know if this help you enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this css, it works for me on your site.

```
.stroke li a{
 margin: 0 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.stroke li a::after{
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: center center;
  transition: all .4s ease-out;
}

.stroke li a:hover::after{
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

Comment: Why should I "try" this code? Please note that you are not answering only to the OP, the answer should be understandable for future readers as well. So please add some explanation to this post, either in text or comments within the code.